# Include image from website in mailitem.HTMLBody

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am currently developing an add-in for Microsoft Outlook that adds an image right before the  tag of an html body.  This image is located on a remote server so the source of the image tag is `http://someserver.com/image.jpg`

This works exactly as expected on a fresh e-mail ( aka a new e-mail )
However when a user clicks reply, or forward for some reason the image source gets changed to cid:image001.jpg and the actual image source gets put in the alt tag.

I am altering the body on the send event as I want the image to be added after the e-mail is finished being written.

The code that is run at the send event

```
void OutlookApplication_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {

        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;

            string image = "<img src='http://someserver.com/attach.jpg' width=\"100\" height=\"225\" alt=\"\" />";
            string body = mailItem.HTMLBody;

            body = body.Replace("</body>", image + "</body>");

            mailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            mailItem.HTMLBody = body;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The proper way to include inline images is with ContentId(cid). What happens is the image is actaully a regular attachment on the email is then referenced by this cid prefix you're seeing. This way the image is available locally and doesn't need to be hosted somewhere. If you then send that message and someone in gmail for example views it gmail automatically converts the cid to a link so that the message displays properly in a browser.

Comment: Furthermore you're probably looking for a solution similar to the one found here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c063b27-7e8a-4963-ad5f-ce7e5ffb2c64/how-to-embed-image-in-html-body-in-c-into-outlook-mail?forum=vsto

Comment: I am not trying to embed an image, I am trying to use a linked image, IE a web hosted image.  For my purposes a static attached image will not work.  As I stated in my original post, with a fresh e-mail this works fine, it is during a reply or forward that the html gets parsed and my image src gets changed

Comment: I understand the what but not the why. What is the problem with outlook handling it how it does? You haven't described what your custom use case is.

Comment: The why isn't important, but I can give you an example if it makes your feel better.  Lets say I'm sending an e-mail with an image of a product that may change before you open your e-mail.  The only way to do this is to host the image and change it as necessary when it updates.  Either way, every language I've ever used allows me to create a proper html e-mail with images hosted on a website.  Even on a clean send Outlook allows me to do this.  The only time it doesn't work is when I use reply or forward

Comment: All you had to say was that it was a dynamic image.. and yes the why IS important which is why I asked. You're asking for help and no ones given you the correct answer for 2 days and you have the audacity to be rude. If I didn't know the answer I wouldn't have continued this conversation with you...

Comment: I had already mentioned that I didn't want an embedded image, to suggest "embed the image" means your not trying to answer the question at hand, either way, I found a way to do it.  Problem solved.

Comment: You have to understand that many times someone is trying to solve a problem using a method more complex than they need. I understood completely what you wrote, but I have no clue where your knowledge starts or ends. It's ultimately your business how you want to interact with people, but I can tell you right now you're only holding yourself back with that type of attitude. P.s. the answer you wrote was what I could have told you 2 days ago if I had more information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a way to do it that works.  What I ended up having to do was create a new mailItem, copy the existing mailitem into it, modify and send that item and cancel the original.  The following code shows how I did it:

```
void OutlookApplication_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {

        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.Inspector currInspector;
            currInspector = outlookApplication.ActiveInspector();
            Outlook.MailItem oldMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = oldMailItem.Copy();
            string image = "<img src='http://someserver.com/attach.jpg' width=\"1\" height=\"1\" alt=\"\" />";
            string body = mailItem.HTMLBody;

            body = body.Replace("</body>", image+"</body>");

            mailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            mailItem.HTMLBody = body;

            mailItem.Send();
            Cancel = true;
            currInspector.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding images inside the ... elements. You can read more about HTML rendering capabilities in the following series of articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Word is used as an email editor in latest Outlook versions.

Do you get any issue with the ItemSend event handler? Does it work?

Comment: I am appending the img tag during the ItemSend event and it works fine on a new e-mail.  The issue is during a reply it tries to embed the image instead of using the src that I provide, which is to say a web address to the image.  I do NOT want to embed or attach the image as that does not work for my particular situation