# Assigning mailItem.HTMLBody with .NET Framework takes too long

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I wrote simple C# Outlook Add-on that reads a mail's body, adds signature etc. and reassing it. But assigning the **mailItem.HTMLBody** takes too long, like **60-70 seconds** long.

`if (mailItem != null) mailItem.HTMLBody = bodyContent;`

I am assuming Outlook tries to verify the new body text, and takes a long time with it. Is there a option to bypass that verification?

Or is something totally different going on?

[Something I tried already.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325678/include-image-from-website-in-mailitem-htmlbody)

At the link above, they suggested to assign `mailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;` but when I checked it, default value is already **olFormatHTML**.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this only happen for a particular value of `bodyContent`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It happens every time, I think. It's noticeable when assigning HTMLBody of large mails. Waiting time increases with mail size.

Comment: I mean, does it matter what the HTML body is? Do you see the same problem if `bodyContent` is something simple, like `<html><body>test</body></html>`

Comment: What matters is the length of the content. I think Outlook tries to verify the HTML tags. (Seeks for any malicious content)

Comment: Possible, but I have never seen HTMLBody assignment taking over a minute . Make sure you have well formatted HTML. Try to compare with HTML body of the same length that includes nothing but plain text. Or an embedded base64 encoded image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try it.